# Why ehcache doesn't propagate expiration events?

Tags: rmi, ehcache

Why ehcache doesn't propagate expiration events ? How do you deal with it ?

Here is my situation. I have two nodes that syncronize with each other using RMI. My config is below:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//localhost:51001/sessionCache|//localhost:51002/sessionCache"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                 properties="hostName=0.0.0.0, port=51002, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cache name="sessionCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="20000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="100000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="60"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       transactionalMode="off">

    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true" />
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false"
            propertySeparator=","/>
</cache>
```

Now imagine following scenario:

1. Login call to server A creates session which is put to replicated cache.
2. Continuous calls to server A to get session object from cache will reset `timeToIdleSeconds` counter for it.
3. Continue calling server A for 65 seconds to make sure that session is going to be expired on server B which was never called after session object was put into cache in step 1.
4. Call server B. Internally it will remove session object **from local cache** and will call `RegisteredEventListeners.internalNotifyElementExpiry` which ends up calling `RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.notifyElementExpired`.

In step 4 I expect server B to send `RmiEventType.REMOVE` to server A. Instead `RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.notifyElementExpired` has following body

```
public final void notifyElementExpired(final Ehcache cache, final Element element) {
    /*do not propagate expiries. The element should expire in the remote cache at the same time, thus
      preseerving coherency.
      */
}
```

It looks like creator of `RMICacheReplicatorFactory` never accounted for `timeToIdleSeconds` algorithm of eviction.

Is manual call of `cache.replace()` right after each `cache.get()` only way to reset TTI (timeToIdle) in cluster ?

Is additional cacheEventListener with `cache.remove()` call in `notifyElementExpired` only way to remove expired element from cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up making hack. Let me know guys if there is more elegant solution.

I created additional cache event listener which looks like this

```
class MyCacheEventListener(properties: Properties) extends CacheEventListener {

  override def notifyElementExpired(cache: Ehcache, element: Element): Unit = {

    cache.getCacheEventNotificationService.notifyElementRemoved(element, false)
  }

  override def notifyElementRemoved(cache: Ehcache, element: Element): Unit = {}
  override def notifyElementEvicted(cache: Ehcache, element: Element): Unit = {}
  override def notifyRemoveAll(cache: Ehcache): Unit = {}
  override def notifyElementPut(cache: Ehcache, element: Element): Unit = {}
  override def notifyElementUpdated(cache: Ehcache, element: Element): Unit = {}
  override def dispose(): Unit = {}
}
```

which is responsible for sending fake `RmiEventType.REMOVE` to cluster. It's specified with scope `local` in config

```
<cacheEventListenerFactory class="com.zzzz.MyCacheEventListenerFactory" listenFor="local" />
```

For refreshing I had to do this after successful `cache.get()`

```
cache.getCacheEventNotificationService.notifyElementUpdated(element, false)
```

It's ugly but not sure what else I could do. Frankly I think Terracotta could easily implement it in their `RMICacheReplicatorFactory`.